# Returning the value of one element of an object in an array of objects in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using the map method I am creating a new array (updated) from an existing array (data) and looking up a third array (members) using a Vue getter and it's working fine if I want to return the member object as below...

```
const updated = data.map(el => ({
      ...el,
      memberId: getters.members.find(m => m.accountKey === el.dataKey)
    }))
```

However, when I try to return just the member object id, by adding '.id' below, I get an type error ""TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

```
const updated = data.map(el => ({
      ...el,
      memberId: getters.members.find(m => m.accountKey === el.dataKey).id
    }))
```

I need to return the id not the entire member object

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to use `array.find`

but if you are trying to get the find or filter from an array.

It's better to use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Because array.find will return only the 1st value of the element that it match. If there are multiple matches it will ignore the the rest.

```
const array = [{name:'user1', id: 1}, {name:'user2', id: 2}];

const result = array.filter(person => person.name === 'user1');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Members are unique as defined by the accountKey which cannot be duplicated, so using find was what I thought would be faster as once the record is found the query stops. Is this not correct?

Comment: Yep its good enough for this case